# FileNotFoundException while trying to write an image using thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to write an image using `ImageIO.write()` inside `run()` method of a thread in java. But it is throwing `FileNotFoundException` and not allowing me to write the image. It is showing stack trace as

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\abc\pqr\abc.jpg (Access is denied)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.spi.FileImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
at answerdetection.AnswerDetection.getId(AnswerDetection.java:286)
at getResult.Threader.run(Threader.java:95)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "t1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
at answerdetection.AnswerDetection.getId(AnswerDetection.java:286)
at getResult.Threader.run(Threader.java:95)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please suggest some solution. Thank You.

Comment: Have you already checked the filesystem's permissions for those directories?

Comment: Check your thread "t1" first it is getting null pointer exception.
Btw if more then one thread try to access a file at the same time u will get Access is denied

Comment: @mschenk74 : no, I haven't checked it. Can you please tell me how to do it? I am using windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: @Siddharth Post some code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the Command Prompt or whatever IDE you are using as an **Administrator** and execute the program again. Else, change the path to a place when you have appropriate writing permissions.

Comment: It worked! I ran the IDE as an administrator and now it is not throwing the exception. But is there some another way?

Comment: Accept this as an answer then. :) You use Windows 7 and normal programs don't have writing rights to C: drive. Change C: to other drive and you'll be able to write it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks ike you have not the permission to write the file in `C:\abc\pqr\`

Comment: that is a folder not a file

Comment: @dharr of course - but to be able to write a file inside that folder one has to have some permissions on the folder also